# How can I resolve this error during a dmg copy operation

Tags: finder, dmg

I am trying to copy a 200GB dmg file between two disks (one firewire, one local) and see this error:

```
The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “mbp_18_06_2011.dmg” can’t be read or written.
(Error code -36)
```

How can I debug / fix?

Answer (score 1):

You can try copying the data using Terminal

Type in sudo ditto ~/sourcefile ~/Destination

Replace "~/sourcefile" by dragging the file you want to copy into the terminal window which will autofill, and do the same with the "~/destination"

Alternatively: sudo ditto -V ~/sourcefile ~/Desktop
This will show you progress and any errors as the files are being copied

[image]

Comment: thanks. would the -nocache option prevent any temporary copies being created? The operation failed with a similar error. BTW, its just one file, ~200GB

Comment: ditto: /Volumes/Backups2011/Old MPB/./mbp_18_06_2011.dmg: Input/output error

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I/O errors means the hard drive has bad sectors hence the reason why you can't successfully copy the data across.

Answer (score 0):

If the dmg is mounted, you'll get that error when trying to copy it I believe. Eject/unmount the dmg file first and try to copy it.